# Call constructor inside another constructor (no matching function to call...) c++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I've written an Array class to create 1d,2d and 3d array and it works fine for every test : example of the constructor of the array class for 2d case:

```
Array::Array( int xSize, int ySize )
{ 
xSize_ = xSize;
ySize_ = ySize;
zSize_ = 1;
vec.resize(xSize*ySize);
}
```

It works fine , but when i need to use this constructor inside of other constructor, i get the "no matching function error" ,
part of my code:

```
class StaggeredGrid
{
public:
StaggeredGrid ( int xSize1, int ySize1, real dx, real dy ) : p_ (2,2) {}
protected:
Array p_;
```

complete error:

```
No matching function for call to Array::Array() 
Candidates are : Array::Array(int)
Array::Array(int, int)
Array::Array(int, int, int)
```

I would appreciate if anybody knows the problem

Comment: This should work in C++. The error is in a part of the source file which you didn't show us. Please copy the full source file (http://sscce.org/) and include the line numbers in the error message.

Comment: You probably should make Array *p_ rather than Array p_ (make it a pointer) and then in the StaggeredGrid constructor do a new or unique_ptr or something like that.

Comment: @RichardChambers please don't recommend using pointers

Answer (score 2):

Your Array class has three constructors, taking one, two, and three ints, respectively. If StaggeringGrid has a default constructor, it will invoke Array::Array(), which doesn't exist, from what you told.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Adding another constructor which gets no parameter, solved the problem.but i'm curious why this happens and why my 2d array constructor is not loaded! (by addign array() , now the array(x,x) is loaded!! )

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that then you declare and don't initialize in the StaggeredGrid's constructor

```
    Array p_;
```

the default constructor should be called, which seems to be missing in your code.

Simple adding empty default constructor should solve a problem.

```
    class Array
    {
    public:
        Array(){}
        // ...
    };
```

Comment: You are just guessing

Comment: "No matching function for call to Array::Array()" is a definite sign of default constructor missing.

Comment: The problem with a default constructor is that OP wants to specify the size at the time the StaggeredGrid is constructed so a default will not do.

Comment: The problem is not missing the default constructor in `Array`, but not initializing the `p_` in one of `StaggeredGrid` constructors

Comment: @Erbureth: thanks, corrected. Of course, that's what I meant to say. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Adding another constructor which gets no parameter, solved the problem.but i'm curious why this happens and why my 2d array constructor is not loaded! (by addign array() , now the array(x,x) is loaded!! )

Comment: There is no way to say why exactly, until you show the rest of code.
The code you showed here has no problem. The problem is somewhere else (most probable - in other StaggeredGrid constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Once you define any of the constructor in a class, the compiler does not defines implicitly default constructor for your class.

In your case you've defined parameterized constructor "**Array( int xSize, int ySize )**" but your are creating a class with default constructor i.e., **Array p_**. This invokes your default constructor which is not exactly found by your compiler.

**Solution:**

Introduce a default constructor in **Array** class